# Can .local files be used during VB6 compile to avoid registering COM ocx and dll files

Tags: com, vb6, build

In an attempt to keep my build machine clean can .local files be used during the compile of an application or is there a better way to keep the bloat off the machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.local is used to force Windows to use the COM DLLs in the VB6 application directory in preference to the most recent version stored in the registry. It doesn't replace the necessity of registering the DLL as Windows need to look in the registry for the CLSIDs of the older version.

Registry free COM DLLs is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345111/how-can-you-force-vb6-to-use-the-dlls-and-ocxs-from-the-app-directory) and involves the creation of a manifest file. Similar in principle to what .NET goes through with it's assemblies except .NET handles this issue automatically and with ActiveX DLL it is more of a manual process.