# How to force a VB6 program to use a dll in a specified folder?

Tags: vb6, manifest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you force VB6 to use the DLLs and OCXs from the app directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345111/how-can-you-force-vb6-to-use-the-dlls-and-ocxs-from-the-app-directory)

I have a small application and it references a DLL named `chkConn.dll`.

For example, I have two different versions of the dll in two different locations. The other one is `C:\chkConn.dll` and the other is `D:\chkConn.dll`. I want my application to use `C:\chkConn.dll` even if I register `D:\chkConn.dll` in my system.

I read about creating manifests,but, I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Very similar to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345111/how-can-you-force-vb6-to-use-the-dlls-and-ocxs-from-the-app-directory

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing is to put the dll(s) you want to use into your application folder. Then create an empty text file *ApplicationName*.exe.local. The **.local** extension tells Windows to load dlls for the exe from that folder first. The interesting thing is the trick works for ActiveX DLLs also.

Comment: thanks Beaner! I'm going to try this.

Comment: This trick does not work if a manifest is embedded into the executable.