# How can I tell the exe to use the local DLL instead of the registered one?

Tags: vb6

I have a VB6 project (using Visual Studio 6) and I'm trying to distribute it. The thing is, we already have an installer which registers some of our DLLs.

I'm performing a test on a client machine, which has already installed the program. When I put my test program on his machine it is still loading the default dlls (Program Files). I compiled the DLLs with my test project but the exe uses the registered DLLs.

How can I use the DLL next to the exe file?

thx

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345111/how-can-you-force-vb6-to-use-the-dlls-and-ocxs-from-the-app-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a freeware called [Make My Manifest](http://vb6zone.blogspot.com/2010/07/make-my-manifest.html) that will do most of the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should only ever have one single location for each dll and it's versioned as such to be backwards compatible.
If you want to use one other than the registered one, you need to use a manifest to specify the desired DLL, or direct COM to bypass the COM system entirely.